# python dictionary key error?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rose/Documents/workspace/METProjectFOREAL/src/test_met4.py", line 79, in   <module>
    table_list.append(table_template % art_temp_dict)
KeyError: 'artifact4'
```

from this code:

```
artifact_groups = grouper(4, html_list, "")  

for artifact_group in artifact_groups:
    art_temp_dict={}
     for artifact in artifact_group:
         art_temp_dict["artifact"+str(artifact_group.index(artifact)+1)] = artifact

    table_list.append(table_template % art_temp_dict)
```

Here is a sample of the CSV:

"artifact4971.jpg","H. 17 1/2 x 16 1/2 x 5 1/2 in. (44.5 x 41.9 x 14 cm)","74.51.2648","4971"
"artifact4972.jpg","Overall: 5 1/2 x 3 3/4 x 4 in. (14.0 x 9.5 x 10.2 cm)","74.51.2592","4972"
"artifact4973.jpg","Overall: 6 5/8 x 7 1/4 x 1 1/4 in. (16.8 x 18.4 x 3.2 cm)","74.51.2594","4973"
"artifact4974.jpg","H. 5 1/2 x 6 3/4 x 11 3/4 in. (14 x 17.1 x 29.8 cm)","74.51.2628","4974"
"artifact4975.jpg","Overall: 10 1/8  7  7 in. (25.7 cm)","74.51.2633","4975"
"artifact4976.jpg","Overall: 7 1/2  5  11 1/2 in. (19.1  12.7  29.2 cm)","74.51.2637","4976"
"artifact4977.jpg","Overall: 10 1/2  7  8 1/2 in. (26.7  17.8  21.6 cm)","74.51.2819","4977"
"artifact4978.jpg","H. 6 3/8 x 14 1/2 x 5 1/4 in. (16.2 x 36.8 x 13.3 cm)","74.51.2831","4978"

I understand that the KeyError signifies that 'artifact4' does not exist, but I don't know why - I am taking data from a large CSV file with almost 6,000 records. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: `artifact_group.index(artifact)+1` may be your problem. Try removing the `+1`.

Comment: Its not possible to know without the csv. print out `"artifact"+str(artifact_group.index(artifact)+1)` and see if there's an `artifact4`. There probably isn't.

Comment: The `KeyError` is signifying that `artifact4` doesn't exist _for one of those 6000 records_. If you want to debug it, the first step is to see _which one_. For example, if you just `print(artifact_group)` inside the `for` loop. The last one to get printed before the exception is the one with a problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever have a situation where the fourth column of the CSV has the same value as one of the earlier columns, the `index` will produce the earlier match and `artifact4` will never be populated. Use this instead:

```
 for i, artifact in enumerate(artifact_group):
     art_temp_dict["artifact"+str(i+1)] = artifact
```

Comment: Great explanation for why it's likely failing. More generally, you should almost never try to recover an index by searching. If you already have the index, just use it. If you don't already have it, use `enumerate` and now you do.

Answer (score 3):

You could make this a lot simpler by using [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of using `csv.reader` and then trying to generate a `dict` out of each row:

```
>>> s='''"artifact4971.jpg","H. 17 1/2 x 16 1/2 x 5 1/2 in. (44.5 x 41.9 x 14 cm)","74.51.2648","4971"
... "artifact4972.jpg","Overall: 5 1/2 x 3 3/4 x 4 in. (14.0 x 9.5 x 10.2 cm)","74.51.2592","4972"
... "artifact4973.jpg","Overall: 6 5/8 x 7 1/4 x 1 1/4 in. (16.8 x 18.4 x 3.2 cm)","74.51.2594","4973"'''
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(s.splitlines(), 
...                         ('artifact1', 'artifact2', 'artifact3', 'artifact4'))
>>> list(reader)
[{'artifact1': 'artifact4971.jpg',
  'artifact2': 'H. 17 1/2 x 16 1/2 x 5 1/2 in. (44.5 x 41.9 x 14 cm)',
  'artifact3': '74.51.2648',
  'artifact4': '4971'},
 {'artifact1': 'artifact4972.jpg',
  'artifact2': 'Overall: 5 1/2 x 3 3/4 x 4 in. (14.0 x 9.5 x 10.2 cm)',
  'artifact3': '74.51.2592',
  'artifact4': '4972'},
 {'artifact1': 'artifact4973.jpg',
  'artifact2': 'Overall: 6 5/8 x 7 1/4 x 1 1/4 in. (16.8 x 18.4 x 3.2 cm)',
  'artifact3': '74.51.2594',
  'artifact4': '4973'}]
```

---

If you really want to build each row dict yourself, it's harder to get wrong if you use a dict comprehension.

The declarative structure strongly encourages you to think about this properly. If you know about [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) you'll probably write something like this:

```
 art_temp_dict={'artifact'+str(i+1): artifact
                for i, artifact in enumerate(artifact_group)}
```

… and if not, something like this—uglier, but still correct:

```
 art_temp_dict={'artifact'+str(i+1): artifact_group[i]
                for i in len(artifact_group)}
```

… rather than trying to recover the index by searching.